# What is the difference between [] and '[] in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have been studying Clojure recently and I saw people using [], '[], () and '() at different places. In some case, [] and '[] are interchangeable.

So I wonder what is the different between these two symbols ?

Comment: i found this helpful -- from _Clojure Progamming_ p115: "am empty list does not need to be quoted, since there is no first item that could be construed as a callable value"

Comment: Thanks for the comment !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'<expr>` is reader syntax that expands to `(quote <expr>)`.  `quote` is a special form that says "don't evaluate this expression, but treat it as a literal instead."  For example `x` evaluates to the value of `x`, whereas `'x` evaluates to a symbol whose name is `"x"`.

So `'()` expands to `(quote ())`, which evaluates to `()`.  Likewise for `[]`.  So there is no difference for *empty* lists and *empty* vectors.

Now let's consider `'(x)`, which is `(quote (x))`.  This evaluates to `(x)`, which is a *literal* list containing the symbol `x`.  Another way of obtaining the same result would be to evaluate `(list 'x)`.  In contrast, evaluating `(x)` calls (or attempts to call) the function bound to `x`.

A similar argument holds for `'[x]` versus `[x]`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please do care to explain why, since my understanding is mostly the same and I'm apparently misinformed.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the third paragraph is wrong. '(x) evaluates to (x), not ('x), which is ((quote x)).

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin — You are correct.  I was attempting to convey the fact that the contents of the list is quoted, but I didn't do that very well.  I'll try to come up with an edit to rectify that.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed this. Happy that you agree :).

Answer (score 4):

read up the topics `macros` and `quoting`

in short `'` is a reader-macro which expands to `(quote ..)` 
therefor `'[]` equals `(quote [])`

what it does - it supresses evaluation (i.e. here `a` is not defined)

```
user=> (quote [a])
[a]

user=> '[a]
[a]

; the following will fails since "a" is not bound
; there is no way to construct an array where the 
; first element is the value of a
user=> [a] 
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context, 
 compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0)
```